# How to upload multiple files(20K+) to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, s3cmd

How to upload multiple files to AWS S3?

I tried two ways and both failed:

1)s3cmd shows following error even the file is only 270KB.

```
   $s3cmd put file_2012_07_05_aa.gz  s3://file.s3.oregon/
   file_2012_07_05_aa.gz -> s3://file.s3.oregon/file_2012_07_05_aa.gz  [1 of 1]
   45056 of 272006    16% in    1s    25.62 kB/s  failed
   WARNING: Upload failed: /file_2012_07_05_aa.gz ([Errno 32] Broken pipe)
   WARNING: Retrying on lower speed (throttle=0.00)
   WARNING: Waiting 3 sec...
```

2) use boto's S3 interface.

The boto library is working fine for me only when I create bucket using "US Standard", if I choose other regions like Oregon, it will fail and displays "Connection reset by peer"

```
def connect_to_s3(access_key, secret_key):
    conn = S3Connection(access_key, secret_key)
    return conn


def percent_cb(complete, total):
    sys.stdout.write('.')
    sys.stdout.flush()

def upload_to_s3(bucket, file_name):
    key = bucket.new_key(file_name)
    key.set_contents_from_filename(file_name,cb=percent_cb, num_cb=10)
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could use [Minio Client aka mc](https://github.com/minio/mc)

using mc mirror this can be achieved

```
 
$ mc mirror localdir S3alias/remotebucket
```

If due to network issue or throttling disconnection happens, Minio Client will start the upload from where it left last like.

```
mc:  Session safely terminated. To resume session ‘mc session resume yarbWRwf’
```

Hope it helps.

Dasclaimer: I work for [Minio](https://minio.io)

Answer (score 1):

Broken pipe errors have historically happened when the socket_timeout value was too low. Please check your ~/.s3cfg file to ensure socket_timeout = 300 is set.

The default was changed from 10 seconds to 300 seconds in:

```
commit b503566c362c81dc8744a569820461c1c39bacae
Author: Michal Ludvig <mludvig@logix.net.nz>
Date:   Mon Apr 11 02:01:08 2011 +0000
* S3/Config.py: Increase socket_timeout from 10 secs to 5 mins.
```

Answer (score 0):

My personal favorite solution is using CyberDuck. You log in with S3 API Key credentials, and it works just like a file system explorer. If you drag your folder with your 20000 files, it will upload them just like that. Downloading is just as simple.